# Tangents along a straight line

Tags: tangent-line

I was looking to solve this geometrical problem. I have a line which is subdivided so that the when it is intersected it creates tangents of equal lengths that are stacked upon each other.

I'm looking to find a way to calculate the length of tangents (in red) that would divide x number of times for a length of line (blue) - [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjOjO.jpg) should explain it better.

Thanks!

Comment: What is known about the focus point, where all the lines intersect? Do we know its coordinates?

Comment: @MattiP.  We know the distance from the top of the top red line and bottom of the bottom red line from the focal point and the angle between these [image 2](https://imgur.com/a/5gnXY8U)